# How can I grep tab

Tags: grep

I want to grep line like this

```
12121 \tab something
```

However, grep don't recognize \t, someone in stackoverflow says we can use -P, but it's hard for me the remember, is there more obvious way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really don't want to use -P
You can use [[:space:]] to represent a tab or whitespace in grep, hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can grep for it

```
grep -P '\t' *
```

OR

```
grep -P 'A\tB' "File.tsv"
```